# Angular 2/4: Array field of injected object is emptied out in child controller

Tags: javascript, angular

EDIT: This I had "splice:" instead of "slice" for my array somewhere and that created the problems.

```
var newArray = this.currentSearchHistoryResponse.searchHistoryList.slice(
startingResult, endingResult);
    this.searchHistories = newArray;
```

I have a class that looks like so:

```
export class SearchHistoryResponse {
  public uuid: string;
  public startTime:Date;
  public endTime:Date;
  public searchHistoryList:SearchHistory[];

  public getPageCount()
  {
    return Math.ceil(this.searchHistoryList.length / 45);
  }
}
```

I've noticed that when I pass an instance of this class from a parent controller into a child controller, the array

```
public searchHistoryList:SearchHistory[];
```

is empty.

My code looks like this

ParentView.html

```
<div style="min-height: 350px">
<childcomponent class="footer-flex-container"
                    [currentPageNumber]="currentPageNumber"
                    [searchHistoryResponse]="currentSearchHistoryResponse">
 </childcomponent>
</div>
```

And the code on the Child controller looks like so:

```
  @Input()
  public set searchHistoryResponse(value: SearchHistoryResponse) {
     if(value)
     {
       console.log("SearchHistoryResponse uuid child controller " + value.uuid);
       console.log("Size of array in parent controller " + value.searchHistoryList.length);
       this._searchHistoryResponse = value;
       this.updateFooter();
     }
  }
```

What could be going on?  How come the array field of the child class is empty?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is currentSearchHistoryResponse?

Comment: @Sajeetharan currentSearchHistoryResponse is the instance of the SearchHistoryResponse that I am injecting from the parent controller into the child controller.

Comment: You are misusing the word "injection".

Comment: if you try to directly access the value instead of using setter does it work ?